# Dynamic Legend Creation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a legend that dynamically updates based off of data i receive, The only problem is that i am getting the variables in the Controller. The code below loops through a shape file and gets a non repeating item from it.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
        {
            if (f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode))
            {
                if (!values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()))
                {
                    values.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString());
                }
            }

        }
      if (count == 0)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Green, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Pink, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Blue, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 3)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Yellow, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 4)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Violet, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 5)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Red, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 6)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Aqua, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 7)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 8)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Brown, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 9)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Coral, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 10)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.DarkKhaki, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                count++;
            }

        }
```

So when the code finishes i have  a string of numbers like 4390,4393,4394 and so on. how can i store these variable to use them later in HTML. I am trying to create a Color Legend that dynamically updates based on the layer i am using. The code below shows the Check box that will route to the controller. Since i always know what teh colors will be i need to update the strings within the html

```
<input type="checkbox" name ="colorLegend" value="ESN" onclick="createEsnLegend();" />ESN
```

is there anyway to store these items to use in the view?

any suggestions are always welcome

Comment: Do you want to store the collection in a javascript array so you can loop through them in a function?

Comment: No i already loop through to store the items in a List but i need to be able to access this list when creating a legend in HTML.@StephenMuecke